# What does "Your Skeetage may vary" joke(?) work in this comment?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

I was reading a meta.SE post about Community user. 
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/301070

The last comment against this question post was "Your Skeetage may vary", and it received 4 upvotes.

The context of the discussion is as follows; to control the uncontrollable Community user bot, members suggested praying to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (probably the most famous member of StackOverflow); the discussion continued on about the methodology of such praying.  At the end of such discussion, this comment was made.

Now, I could understand the word 'Skeetage' refers to some sort of methodological attitude toward praying to, Jon Skeet.  What I don't understand is how does the Skeetage connotate such meaning and make sense as a joke (I think this comment is a joke, but not for sure.)

#### Question

In the discussion of the meta post, how does 'Your Skeetage may vary' joke(?) work?

#### The exerpt of discussion

- I fear the team lost control over that bot! :P – Shadow Wizard Jun 14 '13 at 20:16
- @Undo: I can suspend it, but I'll get yelled at if I do it :P – Manishearth Jun 14 '13 at 20:18
- @ShaWizDowArd they never had control. Control is an illusion, created by Community. The only one with control now is... Mr. Skeet! – Richard J. Ross III Jun 14 '13 at 20:29
- @RichardJ.RossIII: Ha! How do we pray to the Skeet again? – Manishearth Jun 14 '13 at 20:36
- @Manishearth first, you chant his name 3 times... then, you spin around twice, light 5 candles, do the skeet-u-flect, and drink a bowl of milk, because that sounds like fun. There, you've successfully prayed to our god, Mr. Skeet. – Richard J. Ross III Jun 14 '13 at 20:38
- @Richard I think that just buying one of his books would suffice. ;) – Shadow Wizard Jun 14 '13 at 20:44
- @ShaWizDowArd that's like paying a tithe or something, not prayer. – Richard J. Ross III Jun 14 '13 at 20:55
- @Richard OK, but doing what you said before while holding a book of Him would greatly increase chances for response, right? :D – Shadow Wizard Jun 14 '13 at 20:57
- @ShaWizDowArd Our god does not offer guarantees of any kind on his prayers, and is not responsible for any jobs lost due to performing the prayer rituals at work. – Richard J. Ross III Jun 14 '13 at 21:00
- @Sha Your Skeetage may vary. – Undo Jun 14 '13 at 21:05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of

> **Skeetage**

is a play on the word

> **mileage**

Where the outcome is not certain, the full phrase is

> **Your mileage may vary.**

It is a disclaimer used by car manufacturers when stating the mileage their cars get.

In your example the key sentence is

> **Our god does not offer guarantees of any kind**

which is the same as

> **Your mileage may vary.**

NB: The txting usage is "***YMMV***"

Comment: Could you substitute milage with mileage?  I suppose it's typo;  I don't have enough privilege to fix it right away.

Comment: @YukiInoue According to online dictionarties such as [this one](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milage), milage is a variant spelling of mileage.

Comment: I see,, got it.